# Cant write to file with exec

Tags: mysql, exec, puppet, system-administration

I am working with a puppet class which write to my.cnf if specified line isn't there, and it's not working. Here is the code:

```
class mysql-server::configure {
        exec { "enable_binlog":
        path => "/usr/bin/:/usr/sbin/:/usr/local/bin:/bin/:/sbin",
        command => "echo 'log_bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log' >> /etc/mysql/my.cnf",
        onlyif => "grep -c log_bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log' /etc/mysql/my.cnf",
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your `onlyif` query is wrong.

While `grep -c` **prints** a 0 if no matching line is found, it still returns 1.

How about

```
unless => 'grep -q log_bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log /etc/mysql/my.cnf'
```

Note that you probably want to use the `file_line` type from the [stlib module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib) to do the same thing more efficiently.